# Bootstrap Responsive Layout not flowing as required

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my display form (MVC for the record) to layout properly and "respond" when the form gets smaller.

The main layout works but I just can't get the labels and data to drop into the right place as the form gets smaller.

Below is the three modes that I want to display...

[image]

Here's the markup I have... but it just squishes everything up.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Arrive Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                01-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Departure Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                02-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FAILED LAYOUT

[image]

Comment: try to use word-wrap and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Arrive Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6">
                01-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Departure Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                02-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7khespu1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Arrive Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                01-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Departure Date
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                02-Jan-2016
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can go through https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ for better use  I hope it will be helpfull for you

Comment: Well.... That sort of worked.... but it goes from layout 1 straight to layout 3 .... it misses layout 2..... but that will probably be ok... Thanks...

Comment: Went through the bootstrap link provided before posting and it didn't really show how things wrap-down very well... hence the question... but once again,. thanks for taking the time to answer